# 301 redirect rule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What am i doing wrong? this rule isn't working

I want the xyz-banking(old) to xyzbanks(new)

> RewriteRule ^category/xyz-banking/?$ http://www.domainname.com/category/xyzbanks/ [L,R=301]

When there are multiple categories goes to one new category...can i do this?

> RewriteRule ^category/(chicos|chs|rl)/?$ http://www.domain.com/category/apparel/ [L,R=301]

Ofcourse that one is also not working.

Comment: what if you try with "RewriteRule ^/category/blablabla...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both rewrite rules seem to be correct and they should work.

Whenever you browse to: `http://www.domain.com/category/chs/` you will be redirected to `http://www.domain.com/category/apparel/` as requested, etc.

Maybe you have a problem somewhere else:

- Is mod_rewrite enabled?
- Make sure you have `RewriteEngine On` on your `.htaccess` or site configuration.
- If using an `.htaccess` file, Make sure you have an `AllowOverride` directive that allows you to use RewriteRule there.
- Try a simple redirect rule first!
- Check your error and access logs to see if you can spot any error or warning message.
- Take a look at the [URL Rewriting Guide - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)